# How to identify hardware requirement for deploying a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, scalability

How to decide the hardware required to deploy a Ruby on Rails application which will serve following number of requests

5000 - 7000 concurrent requests to be served within 5 sec response time